# Translation of mRNA sequence to amino acid length using Python

Tags: python

I really need help with a computer science question. I'm supposed to make a program that takes an mRNA sequence and returns the length of the amino acid sequence. There are a few assumptions, such as "AUG" is the start codon and "UAA" or "UAG" or "UGA" are the possible stop codons. Basically, the start codon is the first AUG nucleotide triplet it encounters and from there it translates the sequence codon by codon until it encounters a stop codon. The program needs to return a single integer corresponding to the length of the amino acid sequence encoded.
I am so incredibly lost on what to do (I'm a biology major that has never coded before) so any help would be really really appreciated.

```
def Translation(mRNA: str) -> int:
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(mRNA)):
        if i == "AUG":
            count = count + 1
    while True:
        if mRNA[i:i+3] == "UAA" or "UAG" or "UGA":
            break
    print(count) 

Return the length of the protein sequence that is encoded by the given mRNA
   >>>Translation("AUGUGA")
   1
   >>>Translation("ACCUAUGACGUCCUAAGCAGUUUGACG")
   3
   >>>Translation("ACCUAUGAUAACCUAAGCAGUUUGACG")
   3
   >>>Translation("AUGAUGAUGAUGAUGUGAUGAUGAUGA")
   5
   ’’’
```

I have done this but it is clearly not working.

Comment: What is the definition of "length" here?  It is the number of nucleic acids, or something else?

Comment: It is the number of amino acids which would be the number of triplets/codons (or sets of 3 nucleotides). For example, AUG codes for methionine and that is one amino acid (so length of 1).

Comment: @slags Why `Translation("AUGUGA")` is 1, shouldn't it 2?

Comment: UGA is the stop codon and those are not included in the amino acid sequence. The sequence is the start codon and then everything up to the stop codon but not including it so it would actually be 1 (just AUG).

Comment: Why is the correct result for "AUGA...." 5 instead of 1? The first triple is AUG and the second triple is UGA.